# What is the total cost of 55k units?

Tags: finance

Kaplan Ltd. is one of the premier industries that manufactures fan belts for automobiles. If a belt is not sold in the year of production, it becomes defective and has to be scrapped. The following estimates reveal all the costs of Kaplan Ltd.

- If $P(n) = Production$ cost of the nth unit,
  then
  $$P(n) = Rs. 20; 0 < n < 40001$$
  $$P(n)= Rs. 25; n > 40000$$
- Total salary cost for Kaplan Ltd. $Rs. 1.5$ lakh per annum
- Maintenance cost $Rs. 30,000$ per annum
- Fuel supply and electricity cost $Rs. 20,000$ per annum

What is the total cost for Kaplan Ltd., when it sold $55,000 units$ of fan belts in the market in
a particular year?

---

- Fixed Payment = $1,50,000 + 30,000 + 20,000 = 2,00,000$
- Manufacturing Cost = $(40,000 * 20)+(15,000 * 25) = Rs. 11.75 lakhs$
  $$Total cost= Rs. 13.75 lakhs$$

**How should I go from here? I am guessing I need to know the profit generated! But how? How will I end up getting the total cost for $55k$ units?**

Comment: To obtain the total costs sum up all costs. Without the selling price you cannot evaluate the profit. What is the link between Rs amd lakhs?

Comment: There is no link between Rs and lakhs. In India, rupees is the unit like one dollar. And lakhs is something similar to 1 million.

Comment: Ok. It seems that you've found the total costs.

Comment: Clarification: 1 lakh = 100k, not 1 million.

Comment: Yes, I found it already on google. Anyway thanks. Is somerhing still unclear?